# How to connnect Arduino to Wemos D1 (send data)?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, lcd, nodemcu, ds18b20

I made a project with an **Arduino Uno**, a 16x2 LCD **display** and a DS18B20 **temperature sensor**. It shows the temperature in the display:

[image: Arduino Uno with 16x2 LCD and temperature sensor]

I want to connect it to Internet so I got a Wemos D1 Mini. It works great: it send data through my router.

But I need to connect my project with the Wemos D1 Mini:
[image: Wemos D1 Mini pins]
I think that I just need to send the data (temperatures grades) from my project to Wemos so then Wemos resolve it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

- A) Throw out the Arduino, and just connect your display and sensor to the WeMos directly.
- B) Connect the Arduino to the WeMos using UART, SPI or I²C and send the temperature value to the WeMos. Keep in mind that the Arduino UNO is a 5V device, and the maximum voltage for the ESP8266 is 3.3V, so you'll need a level shifter.
  You can send the temperature as a binary value (beware of framing errors), but the easiest way is to use a text-based protocol. Since you just have to send a single value, you can just use a single delimiter (e.g. new line). That makes it very easy to parse.

Comment: Option A): Do I need a I2C converter between Wemos and LCD? Like this: https://www.digibay.in/image/cache/data/sachinelectronics/ED01/ED01-09-0020-A-600x600.jpg. Option B: Do you have a sample code or schematic code? Thanks.

Comment: A) you could do that to save pins, but you don't have to. B) Google for Serial input basics by Robin2 on forum.arduino.cc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Wemos D1 only as a 'network adapter', put a firmware into esp8266. 'Classic' is Espressif AT firmware in esp with WiFiEsp library in your sketch. New option is WiFi Link firmmware in the esp with [WiFi Link library](https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-library-wifilink) used in your sketch.

Both libraries recommended by me (WiFiEsp and WiFiLink) have standard Arduino networking API like the Ethernet and WiFi library.

[WiFi Link firmware](https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-firmware-wifilink) is an Arduino sketch for the esp8266.